# Unity crashes as the program goes through WaitForSeconds the last time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, ienumerator

i have a strange problem. My Code works fine. Everything works as it should until it goes the last time through a foreach loop. The code:

```
public List<string> waveInput = new List<string>(); //die Eingabe der Welle als Zeichenfolge
public List<GameObject> enemyTyps = new List<GameObject>();
public List<Vector3> path = new List<Vector3>();
public GameObject tempPathStart;
public int currentWave = 0;
public int currentAmountOfEnemies;

private int spawnAmountOfEnemies;
private double spawnDelay;
private List<GameObject> enemyToSpawn = new List<GameObject>();

void Start() {
    path.Add(tempPathStart.transform.position);
    StartCoroutine(function());
}

IEnumerator function() {

    while(waveInput.Capacity >= currentWave) {

        if(waveInput[currentWave] == "" && currentAmountOfEnemies <= 0) {
            currentWave++;
            enemyToSpawn.Clear();
            spawnAmountOfEnemies = 0;
        } else if(currentAmountOfEnemies <= 0) {
            string _substring = waveInput[currentWave].Substring(0, waveInput[currentWave].IndexOf(";") + 1);
            ManageSubstring(_substring);

            for(int i = 0; i < spawnAmountOfEnemies; i++) {

                foreach(GameObject element in enemyToSpawn) {
                    this.SpawnEnemy(element);
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)spawnDelay);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void ManageSubstring(string _substring) {
    string _tempStringAmount = "";
    string _tempStringDelay = "";
    string _tempStringType = "";
    bool _switchAmountDelay = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < _substring.Length; i++) {
        char c = _substring[i];

        if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {

            if(_switchAmountDelay) {

                _tempStringDelay += c;
            } else {
                _tempStringAmount += c;
            }
        } else if(c == ';') {

        } else if(c == '.') {
            _tempStringDelay += c;
        } else {
            _switchAmountDelay = true;
            _tempStringType += c;
        }
    }
    spawnDelay = double.Parse(_tempStringDelay);
    spawnAmountOfEnemies = int.Parse(_tempStringAmount);

    foreach(char c in _tempStringType) { //die Buchstaben in GameObjekte / Gegner umwandeln
        int _tempConvertedInt = TranslateStringToInt(c);
        enemyToSpawn.Add(enemyTyps[_tempConvertedInt]);
    }
}

int TranslateStringToInt(char pToConvertChar) {
    List<char> _alphabet = new List<char>() {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    return _alphabet.IndexOf(pToConvertChar);
}

void SpawnEnemy(GameObject prefab) {
    currentAmountOfEnemies++;
    GameObject e = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
    e.transform.position = path[0];
}
```

the very strange thing as i already said is: the code works, even the line works fine until it goes through the last time. Then Unity crashes and i have no idea what i should do. If some more code is needed for context just say.

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: well theres a lot of unknown variable contents in there, waveInput.capacity is not its length, so it could keep going round that first bit of while loop for a long long time or crash because the waveinput is not that long..

Comment: Any chance you can add the Stack trace or other output about the crash?

Comment: unity just freezes which means there is no output, that's why i asked the users of stack :D

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled your script into the debugger and stepped through the last iteration:

When the iteration is over, it goes back into the while() loop which encloses the whole body of `function()`.

- The while condition remains true since `waveInput.Capacity` is greater than the currentWave (still zero).
- The `if(waveInput[currentWave] == "" && currentAmountOfEnemies <= 0)` is false since the waveInput[] array has an element zero which is not "", and the enemycount was not reset yet.
- the `else if(currentAmountOfEnemies <= 0)` condition is also false since the current amount was not reset.
- nothing more in the while-loop, nothing chagned, you have an endless-loop, which never hits a yield return. This locks up the Update() cycle of Unity and only allow killing.

Comment: Note: I just added it to an empty object, linked two prefabs as spawns, and set two wave-inputs, assigning this string to test: "6a1.25;6a1.25;"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are a few things i forgot to mention. Like if a object gets destroyed the currentAmountOfEnemies gets reduced by one. I made some changes and now unity doesn't freeze anymore. Still not perfect but i made progress today and you helped a lot.